# Sort an array[(int, int)] in order to a list in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting, quicksort

I am currently working on Spark framework using Scala.
I have an array C: Array[(int, int)] to which i want to sort according to order of a map A:Map[int,int]. The code is given below:

```
line 1:import scala.util.Sorting
line 2: object Test {
line 3:     def main(args: Array[String]){
line 4:     val A = Map(5 -> 41, 1 -> 43, 2 -> 41, 3 -> 59,4 -> 51 )
line 5:     val B= A.toList.sortBy(x => x._2)
line 6:     B.foreach(println)
line 7:     val C=Array((1,15),(2,9),(3,6),(4,3),(5,4))
line 8:     Sorting.quickSort(C)(Ordering[(Int)].on(k => (A.get(k._1).get)))
line 9:     for(j <- 0 to C.length-1){
line 10:        println(C(j))
line 11:       }
line 12:    }
line 13: }
```

When I sort the A according the value part (line 5) and print, i get the output (line 6) like this:

```
(5,41)
(2,41)
(1,43)
(4,51)
(3,59)
```

But when i sort C according the key part of A (line 8), i get the following output (line 9-11)

```
(2,9)
(5,4)
(1,15)
(4,3)
(3,6)
```

As both (5,41) and (2,41) have same value and, in B (5,41) appears before (2,41). But after sorting C according to key part of A, why 2 is appearing before 5. Why is the result not uniform in both B and C?

Please suggest me the changes in the code to get a uniform result in both B and C. I want the C as: `(5,4) (2,9) (1,15) (4,3) (3,6)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` is by-design unordered hence sorting by `value` alone may result in nondeterministic order.  If your business logic allows changing of the sorting criteria, consider making it consistent by ordering by `value + key` on both the `Map` and `Array`:

```
import scala.util.Sorting

val A = Map(5 -> 41, 1 -> 43, 2 -> 41, 3 -> 59, 4 -> 51 )
val B = A.toList.sortBy(x => (x._2, x._1))

B
// res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,41), (5,41), (1,43), (4,51), (3,59))

val C = Array((1,15),(2,9),(3,6),(4,3),(5,4))

Sorting.quickSort(C)(Ordering[(Int, Int)].on( k => (A.get(k._1).get, k._1) ))

C
// res23: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((2,9), (5,4), (1,15), (4,3), (3,6))
```

As a side note, to avoid crash due to key not found, consider using `gerOrElse` with a default (e.g. Int.MaxValue, etc):

```
Sorting.quickSort(C)(Ordering[(Int, Int)].on( k => (A.getOrElse(k._1, Int.MaxValue), k._1) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `A.get(k._1).get` which makes your ordering non deterministic as you see with

`B.map(_._1).indexOf(k._1)` which will correctly order based on the index of the key in B, which is what you want.

Comment: When  i replaced A.get(k._1).get by B.map(_._1).indexOf(k._1), i got an error which says " value indexOf is not a member of Scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int]" .